# `apache2ctl restart` makes apache forget about cgi-bin

Tags: debian, apache-2.4

On my Debian machine (running the apache as packaged by Debian, package 2.4.7-1), every time apache restarts through `apache2ctl restart` or `apache2ctl graceful`, it forgets about my cgi-bin directory:

```
me@aram:~$ sudo apache2ctl graceful-stop
me@aram:~$ sudo apache2ctl graceful
httpd not running, trying to start
me@aram:~$ curl -s http://localhost/cgi-bin/hello
Hello world, from a cgi script.
me@aram:~$ sudo apache2ctl graceful
me@aram:~$ curl -s http://localhost/cgi-bin/hello
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /cgi-bin/hello was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>
me@aram:~$ sudo apache2ctl graceful
me@aram:~$ curl -s http://localhost/cgi-bin/hello
Hello world, from a cgi script.
me@aram:~$ sudo apache2ctl graceful; sudo apache2ctl graceful
me@aram:~$ curl -s http://localhost/cgi-bin/hello
Hello world, from a cgi script.
me@aram:~$ sudo apache2ctl graceful
me@aram:~$ curl -s http://localhost/cgi-bin/hello
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /cgi-bin/hello was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>
me@aram:~$ sudo apache2ctl graceful
me@aram:~$ curl -s http://localhost/cgi-bin/hello
Hello world, from a cgi script.
```

This is perfectly repeatable; if I stop the server completely and restart it, it's fine. After that, a restart (graceful or not) switches behaviors. Unfortunately, the regular `logrotate` job issues a graceful restart, so I need to make it so that Apache always knows about `cgi-bin`.

There's nothing in the access or error log to mark a "will know about cgi" restart from a "won't know about cgi" restart. If people comment with suggestions as to how to make the logs more verbose, I'll try that and update this.

I'm using the config that the Debian package comes with (so it's configured by symlinking a bunch of files in `-enabled` directories to existing files in `-available` directories). Here, for reference, are what my `-enabled` directories contain:

```
me@aram:/etc/apache2$ ls *-enabled
conf-enabled:
000-local-routerblock.conf  charset.conf  javascript-common.conf      other-vhosts-access-log.conf  serve-cgi-bin.conf
apache2-doc.conf            dwww.conf     localized-error-pages.conf  security.conf

mods-enabled:
access_compat.load  authn_core.load       authz_host.load  cgi.load      dir.load    filter.load       mpm_prefork.load  reqtimeout.load  status.load
alias.conf          authn_file.load       authz_user.load  deflate.conf  dnssd.conf  mime.conf         negotiation.conf  setenvif.conf    userdir.conf
alias.load          authz_core.load       autoindex.conf   deflate.load  dnssd.load  mime.load         negotiation.load  setenvif.load    userdir.load
auth_basic.load     authz_groupfile.load  autoindex.load   dir.conf      env.load    mpm_prefork.conf  reqtimeout.conf   status.conf

sites-enabled:
000-default.conf
```

All of those, except for `000-local-routerblock.conf`, are as shipped by Debian. I've verified that removing that config file fixes the issue, so I suspect it's some odd interaction between that file and the default `serve-cgi-bin.conf` file. Again, though, no evidence in the logs.

Contents of `000-local-routerblock.conf`:

```
Redirect /router /cgi-bin/router
<Location "/cgi-bin/router">
  AuthUserFile /usr/lib/cgi-bin/routerblock/htpasswd
  AuthGroupFile /dev/null
  AuthName ByPassword
  AuthType Basic
  Require user router
</Location>
```

Contents of `serve-cgi-bin.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    <IfModule mod_cgi.c>
        Define ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_cgid.c>
        Define ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
    </IfModule>

    <IfDefine ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN>
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
    </IfDefine>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

EDIT: I've solved this now, in terms of "I made it work". I have no idea why this works, and that it does almost certainly indicates a bug in this version of Apache. I'm leaving the bounty up for someone to answer as to what is/was going on.

In any case, the solution was not in any of the config. files I quoted. Remember, the rest of this configuration is exactly stock Debian, nothing custom about the configuration. The Debian `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` includes the line:

```
LogLevel warn
```

In the stock configuration, there are no other `LogLevel` statements, except for a commented out one in the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`. (that entire file is inside a `<VirtualHost *:80>` tag; it sets up `DocumentRoot` and the access log, but nothing else)

I was messing around with `LogLevel` settings trying to get more information in my logs when I stumbled across this: if I have a `LogLevel` statement inside that `VirtualHost` tag, it works. So now in addition to the `LogLevel warn` that's in the main apache config, I also have a `LogLevel warn` inside the `<VirtualHost *:80>` tag in `000-default.conf`. This works. If I have extra time this weekend, I think I'll try to set up a virtual machine to reproduce this in as clean an environment as possible, and then file a Debian bug.

Comment: Given that you're on Debian, is there any difference when using the `service` or `invoke-rc.d` calls? Like `server apache2 restart`

Comment: @OliverSalzburg - only the difference you'd expect from knowing how `service apache2` handles `restart` vs `reload` - since `service apache2 restart` actually does a shutdown then restart, CGI is always found. With `service apache2 reload`, I get the switching behavior.

Comment: It does sound like a bug that it toggles between these two modes when reloading with the exact same configuration.

Comment: Now reported as a bug to Debian: https://bugs.debian.org/743860

Comment: I wrote a hard apache restarter script for the task: first it tried a graceful stop, then waited some seconds, and then killed what remained, waited some seconds and made a start. It wasn't really beautiful, but worked...

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments and link to a bug report above, this does appear to have been a valid bug that has been recently resolved; from https://bugs.debian.org/743860 :

> From: Jean-Michel Vourgère
>   To: 743860-done@bugs.debian.org
>  
>   Subject: Re: apache2: Apache forgets about /cgi-bin on restart
>  
>   Date: Mon, 08 Jun 2015 00:12:12 +0000
>
> Source: apache2 Source-Version: 2.4.10-1
>
> Hello
>
> We believe that the bug you reported is fixed.
>
> Thank you for reporting the bug, which will now be closed.  If you
>   have further comments please address them to 743860@bugs.debian.org,
>   and a maintainer will reopen the bug report if appropriate.